# Configuring an SSH tunnel with Transmit

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, sftp, tunnel

Is there any way to configure [Transmit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmit_(FTP_client)) so that it connects to an SFTP server through some SSH tunnel? (without having to launch the SSH tunnel via command line)

E.g., with WinSCP on Microsoft Windows, I can do the following:

[image]

Comment: If that functionality is not built-in, you may use "SSH Tunnel Manager": https://www.tynsoe.org/stm/